# Zakat to sister

Tags: ramadan, zakat

Salam, i need advice. I have a sister who has 5 kids, 3 girls, and 2 boys all very young. They are all good in their studies. They live in Pakistan. The husband works abroad, but he doesn't send my sister any money he just uses it for his own personal pleasures and he goes around with other females not providing my sister with anything, and also he sometimes doesn't work at all.

Is it okay to give her zakat money

Answer (score 0):

Yes!

**In Islam, supporting family members, especially in times of need, is highly encouraged.** If your sister is facing financial hardship due to her husband's negligence, it is permissible to give her Zakat money to help her and her children.

Zakat, one of the Five Pillars of Islam, is meant to **assist those in need**, and your sister's situation aligns with the criteria for Zakat eligibility.

*Note that it is essential to ensure that Zakat is given directly to your sister for her and her children's benefit.*